# Trying to dismiss Progress Dialog

Tags: android

I am using Async Task to perform some operations in my database. During the operation, I'm showing a progress dialog and when it operations are finish I want to dismiss it but it doesn't work.

```
private ProgressDialog progressDialog; 

private void showProgressDialog(String title, String message)
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    progressDialog.setTitle(title); //title

    progressDialog.setMessage(message); // message

    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    progressDialog.show();
}

private class InsertFoodAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0){
        InsertFood p = new InsertFood(Food.this,mBDD);
        p.InsertFood();

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showProgressDialog("Please wait...", "Your message");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Can you help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: Shouldn't progressDialog.dismiss() be called on the main UI thread?

Comment: @SparkyRobinson `onPostExecute()` does run on the main UI thread.

Comment: I just tested this code, and it worked just fine for me having `InsertFoodAsyncTask` as an inner class of the Activity.

Comment: Why setCancelable(true) ?

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

replace:

```
progressDialog.show();
```

for:

```
progressDialog = progressDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems all correct in your code. `onPostExecute()` already make it run on ui thread. But still try to check with this also.

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                    if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
                    {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
               }
            });
```

Comment: It works without modifications, I putted also the method calling the progress dialog in onResume, so it was launched two times...sorry for the loss of time !